# Using the servicenow.itsm ansible collection for a proxied ServiceNow instance

Tags: ansible, servicenow

Had anyone found a way to use servicenow.itsm ansible collection to pull information from or manage a SaaS ServiceNow instance located behind an http proxy ?

PS: adding the following to my playbook did not work :

```
environment: 
  http_proxy: "{{ proxy }}"
```

Thanks !

Comment: You may want to try `https_proxy: "{{ proxy }}"` in addition, and also update your question with what is happening instead of what you expect. Right now, your question is "it didn't work"

Comment: guess what, it worked by addding the https_proxy even though it is not using httpS !
thanks man !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though the proxy is using http and not https
you have to add :

```
https_proxy: http://<proxy_IP>:<proxy_port>
```

thanks to [mdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/mdaniel)

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. Also, be aware that the `https` is about the **target** URL, not the **proxy** URL; almost every connection to the _proxy_ is via http, but the _upstream URL_ is very, very likely https